# Mouseover on disabled button showing handsymbol in firefox

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net website I'm disabling the asp:button based on condition.
But even it has disabled, when i take move on the button its showing hand symbol in firefox.
why can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS should do the trick.

```
input[type=button][disabled], button[disabled] {
    cursor:default;
}
```

I don't do ASP.NET, but if it's a standard button element, this will work.